Есть ли способ эффективно отображать ts в phpstorm?
Всем привет, для работы использую phpStorm.
Однако никак не пойму есть ли в среде удобная и более дружелюбный способ отображать тип переменной чем видеть название его интерфейса.
Хотелось бы мониторить хотя бы часть того что находится внутри.


посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1579880/2659
